# IBInspectable in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, interface-builder

Does any one know how to use an IBInspectable in Xamarin or if it is possible?

They only thing I have found on the topic is [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32387/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-support) which doesn't hold much promise. Also cant find anything about it in the API docs

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I assume you didn't find anything? I, too, cannot seem to find any material regarding `IBInspectable` or `IBDesignable` in the context of Xamarin. I found your linked forum post before this question. It hasn't been updated since you posted your question.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find anything so assumed it wasn't supported, would be nice to have but I don't think it is at the top of anyone's list :(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something similar(Custom Controls). It works the same as IBInspectable or IBDesignable.

Check this official link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/

Comment: Nice this is exactly what I was looking for.