# Autogenerated outlet in designer.cs type of subclass

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I want to know whether it's possible for Xamarin Studio to set the type of an autogenerated outlet in, say, `myview.designer.cs` to the sublcass of a control within the `.xib`.

For example, I've subclassed `NSButton` to create some custom UI for buttons throughout the app.

I have my class defined as something like this, using the `Register` attribute so it's visible to the Objective-C runtime:

```
[Register("AppButton")]
public class AppButton : NSButton
{
    ...
}
```

Within XCode, I have then set the custom class to `AppButton` on my `NSButton`s. If I open the `.xib` in a text editor, I can see the `customClass` attribute on my buttons:

`<button id="bxh-qr-g81" ... customClass="AppButton">`

But when Xamarin Studio has listened for the changes, and updated the designer file, I always seem to get the outlet with a type of `NSButton` instead of `AppButton`.

```
[Register ("MyView")]
partial class MyView
{
    [Outlet]
    AppKit.NSButton MyButton { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I would like it to be the type of my custom class:

```
[Register ("MyView")]
partial class MyView
{
    [Outlet]
    AppButton MyButton { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The main reason for this is that I want to set some properties within `AwakeFromNib`, and it's a little tedious to cast it every time. It would also be nice for the compiler to throw an error if the type changed, rather than a runtime error, assuming I don't check that it really is the type of `AppButton`.

If I could set the properties directly on my subclass within XCode, this wouldn't be an issue. But as far as I can tell, [`IBInspectable` or `IBDesignable` doesn't seem to be supported by Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31402047/1229237).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by:

- Creating the subclass like below
- Building Xamarin studio first
- opening xcode check for `CustomButton.h` and `CustomButton.m` file
- Set the class type in xcode it should appear in the drop down:
  [image]
- Creating the outlets again. should then look like this:

  ```
  [Outlet]
  AppName.iOS.CustomButton customButton { get; set; }
  ```

I think you mean `UIButton` too not `NSButton`

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;

namespace EdFringe.iOS
{
    [Register ("CustomButton")]
    public class CustomButton : UIButton
    {
        public CustomButton ()
        {
        }

        public CustomButton (IntPtr p) : base(p)
        {
            //this one i think is used to create the obj-c object.
        }

        public CustomButton (NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
        {
            // This one i think is used when creating the xib.
        }

        //Custom stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach works. I think the key difference is that you create the outlets _after_ setting the custom class. If you create the outlet first, and _then_ set the custom class, it will still have the type `NSButton` rather than `AppButton` in `designer.cs`. So I guess the issue is Xamarin Studio is not detecting the type has changed. At least that's what seems to be happening for me in v5.10.3. I still don't like the idea that the custom class could change, and the type won't in the `designer.cs`. We're using Cocoa for an OS X app, not Cocoa Touch, so it's `NSButton`s for us.

Comment: Ah sorry not done much OSX dev thought it was a typo. Yeah when I was testing it would only work in that order, not great that doesn't pick up the changes after the outlet is set, could file a bug.