# How to make programmatic changes to views in the controller appear in the storyboard

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

I recently inherited a Xamarin project where I am to work on the iOS project. Going over several tutorial I figured I was ready, however the person before me did not use storyboards or controllers! They did all customization of views in files named LoginScreens.cs (basically controller files from the looks of it).

For learning purposes and ease of transition I would like to get a storyboard going in this project. So I created a storyboard titled `Main` and added a ViewController and essential copy and pasted the view customization code used in the `LoginScreen.cs` into my controller.

To be a little more specific, I have a `Main.Storyboard` that looks like this:

[image]

Where I am using editText boxes and a button to act as place holders for what I actually do to them in the `ViewController.cs`.

This all seems to register and builds properly however when I run the debugger on iPhone 6s iOS 9.3 I get the following:

[image]

The changes appear to show, but all my storyboard iOS designer views remain in place. I am trying to see if there is a way to reflect the changes made in the controller on the storyboard.

**TL;DR:** I'm trying to alter some views in a programmatic way in my ViewController.cs file. These views were originally added via the iOS designer and for customization purposes, they were edited in the controller. I want to see the visual alteration I make on a view in the controller, reflect in the iOS designer and when I debug.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to go from a project where views were all done programmatically to implementing storyboards. This is a **Big** change and will take some time to convert the views over.

In the cs file there will be things like `Add(passwordTextFeild)` which are going to add more views to your storyboard view, hence why you get alot of views in your login view. You wont be able to see these in the storyboard as they are done at runtime.

If you are looking for IBDesignable this is more for custom controls and you still will have to add code to be able to see the changes from the .cs file in the storyboard.

Check my Question for [IBInspectable/IBDesignable in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31402047/1107580)

> Check this official link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/

Probably not what you wanted to hear but the UI in iOS projects tend to be done in one of the three methods:

- All programmatically
- Storyboards
- Xibs

There are tons of questions/blog posts (even a [video](https://www.raywenderlich.com/51992/storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-code-the-great-debate)), weighting up the pros and cons of each. So possibly the last developer felt it was best to do it programmatically

Comment: thank you for the reply. this project is still in it's infancy(only one scene for the iOS app) So I may look into having the first page be mostly code based and then from here on out using story boards(is that possible?) or I may rewrite from scratch and go at it with an all storyboard approach

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting, `IBDesignable`, that you can add to the declaration of UI classes in Swift or Objective-C. That tells Xcode the those UI objects have a custom interface that you want to be presented in Interface Builder.

I have no idea how (or even if you could) you would use IBDesignable in Xamarin/C#. If its not supported for Xamarin then you're probably out of luck.

I suggest you search on "Xamarin IBDesignable" on the net.